# Android AppWidget maps activity problem

Tags: android, android-mapview

Right.

So I have an app widget.

It has 4 buttons, one one of the buttons I want it to show me the current location of the user on the map.

So - I make a new activity as below:

```
package com.android.driverwidget;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;



public class MyLocation extends MapActivity{



        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
          super.onCreate(icicle);

          setContentView(R.layout.main);

          MapView myMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
          MapController mapController = myMapView.getController();

          List<Overlay> overlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
          MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this,             myMapView);
          overlays.add(myLocationOverlay);
          myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        }


          protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

            return false;
          }




}
```

And then I added the appropriate uses library line to the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MyLocation"
    android:label="myLocation">
     </activity>

   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Ok yet - when I run the app the following errors occur, looks like it cannot find the MapActivity class, im running it on the GoogleApps 1.5 instead of normal android 1.5 as well.

http://pastebin.com/m3ee8dba2

Somebody plz help me - i am now dying.

Answer (score 9):

Fix your manifest by adding/moving

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

into *application*.

Comment: I think in question he already mention that he added particular this library in his manifest file.@digitarald.

Comment: yes, he did. he needed to move it into *application* though. answer just didn't get accepted because the user is gone.

Answer (score 1):

When you creating this project you have to choose Google APIs project not only AVD.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem might be related to this bug:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/904fae350cda3ebc

Comment: hmmm yeah possibly i guess it could be - think its fixed with 1.5 _r3?