# Problem with resolving superclass of a MapView ("Could not find class" problem)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I'm trying to add MapView to one of my application.
View with correct mapView is added.
Permissions in Manifest are also following rules.
Project compiles with out a problem.
Library with maps is added.

But I'm still receiving this error.

Anyone had same problem and found a solution?

If you need more data, just let me know.

```
02-17 14:16:22.196: WARN/dalvikvm(20884): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet/gynsoft/citydusseldorf/MapViewController; (27)
02-17 14:16:22.196: WARN/dalvikvm(20884): Link of class 'Lnet/gynsoft/citydusseldorf/MapViewController;' failed
02-17 14:16:22.204: ERROR/dalvikvm(20884): Could not find class 'net.gynsoft.citydusseldorf.MapViewController', referenced from method net.gynsoft.citydusseldorf.startActivity$5.onClick
02-17 14:16:22.204: WARN/dalvikvm(20884): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 121 (Lnet/gynsoft/citydusseldorf/MapViewController;) in Lnet/gynsoft/citydusseldorf/startActivity$5;
```

Comment: What specifically is the superclass of `net.gynsoft.citydusseldorf.MapViewController`?

Comment: this is just identifier of a class in a package. net.gynsoft.citydusseldorf - is a package where MapViewController.class is located.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Im getting the exact same problem. My code was working fine, copied my maps class from one project to the other and now this, tested on emulator and T-Mobile G2.

Comment: only by opening new project and doing whole job again in different project.

Comment: The solution to my problem at least was solved with this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153920/android-appwidget-maps-activity-problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must have referenced maps.jar library externaly rather then selecting google add on platform target for your application.

Select Google API as a  Target instead of adding maps.jar file externaly.

This will for sure remove this problem as i also faced it before

Comment: I've changed build target couple of times, cleaned project, reinstalled nothing works. Worst part, I was using maps in two last projects and I didn't encountered this kind of a problem, heh.

Comment: are you using Default Google API as target instead of Android 1.6 or higher as target ?

Comment: yep I tried with 1.6/2.1/2.2 - all Google APIs - no effect :(.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this error when I run an app that requires maps in the standard emulator. You need an emulator running Google API's as opposed to the standard one.

You can do this in the Android SDK and AVD manager.

Answer (score 0):

Create lib folder, libs folder is for native libraries. I made it, add library to lib and to build path as internal library and it works!